# How to render and display emoji in in ngx-toastr notification?

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr, markwon

I use `ngx-toastr` in an angular app to pass and display a notification to the end user. The notification messages are provided by a back-end after a `HTTP Request`. Some of the returned notifications are in `markdown` format and they contain `emojis`. Am able to render the markdown in HTML but not the emojis. The emojis are displayed in text e.g. `smiley`.

```
this.toastrService.warning(
     `Note: ${This is the message containing :emoji:}`,
     '',
     {
        "positionClass": "toast-top-left",
        "enableHtml": true,
        ....
    }
)
```

Any hint or idea how to display an emoji as it must be and not as text?